# Reference on spectral fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, laplacian, fractional-calculus

Are  there Harnack type inequalities and Schauder type estimates for the spectral fractional Laplacian. References are welcome.

Comment: (Spectral  fractional Laplacian means the operator obtained by raising to a power the eigenspectrum in the spectral decomposition of the Laplacian)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a reliable entry point to the literature: [What Is the Fractional Laplacian?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09767)

> The purpose of this work is two-fold: (i) to give a comprehensive
>   report of the commonly used definitions of the fractional Laplacian
>   and examine their differences in bounded domains, and (ii) to
>   quantitatively assess the available numerical methods developed for
>   each definition. Of significance is the inclusion of recent work on
>   implementing methods for nonzero boundary value problems. This work
>   may be of use to practitioners looking to gain insight into which
>   fractional Laplacian definition and associated numerical methods may
>   be appropriate for their application. We present new solvers and
>   discuss our implementation of existing numerical methods for
>   discretizing the fractional Laplacians.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google Scholar search returns ["An extension problem related to the fractional Laplacian" by L. Caffarelli and L. Silvestre](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03605300600987306), an online preprint of which can be found [on Arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608640),

which itself cites ["Properties of the solutions of the linearized Monge-Ampère equation  by L. Caffarelli and C. Gutiérrez"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.626.6252&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

However it's not clear to me that the latter actually proves an Harnack inequality for **fractional** operators.

Comment: It does prove Harnack inequality for the fractional Laplace operator, but for a different one: full-space with zero (Dirichlet) boundary condition.

Comment: That said, I realise the methods of Caffarelli and Silvestre paper extend naturally to the extension problem for the spectral fractional Laplacian. I checked the literature, and the result is given in [*Harnack's inequality for fractional nonlocal equations*](http://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcds.2013.33.3153) by Pablo Raúl Stinga and Chao Zhang.

Answer (score 1):

On the probability side, this operator was extensively studied by Zhen-Qing Chen, Panki Kim, Renming Song and Zoran Vondraček. I always thought that Harnack inequality was proved in already in their first paper on that subject, [*Potential theory of subordinate killed Brownian motion in a domain*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00440-002-0251-1) (by R. Song and Z. Vondraček). Only now I realised it is not there.

It appears Harnack inequality was first proved by P. Kim and Ante Mimica in [*Harnack inequalities for subordinate Brownian motions*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejp/1465062359). A general version, and much more, can be found in more recent [*Potential theory of subordinate killed Brownian motion*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/0000-000-00/S0002-9947-2018-07358-5/home.html).

All papers mentioned above can be found on arXiv, as well as on websites of the authors.

---

Regarding Schauder estimates, I do not think this is available in the probability literature. Quite likely the result can be found on the PDE side, which, unfortunately, I do not know well.

*Edited:* On the PDE side, Harnack inequality is proved in [*Harnack's inequality for fractional nonlocal equations*](http://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/dcds.2013.33.3153) by Pablo Raúl Stinga and Chao Zhang. Quite likely follow-ups to that paper contain regularity results you are interested in.