# Fractional laplacian on $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and symmetry

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fractional-calculus

Let $s\in(0,1)$, $u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n),$ i define the fractional laplacian of $u$ in the following way:
$$(-\Delta)^su(x)=C(n,s)P.V.\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\,dy,\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
or equivalently:
$$ (-\Delta)^su(x)=\frac{C(n,s)}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{2u(x)-u(x+y)-u(x-y)}{|y|^{n+2s}}\,dy,\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n. $$
My question is how to extend this definition to $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that:
$$ \mathcal{F}(-\Delta)^s v=|\cdot|^{2s}\mathcal{F}v,\quad\forall v\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)? 
\tag{3}$$ Here $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform. In what sense does the equation in (3) hold? Than is possible to prove that:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u(-\Delta)^sv\,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}v(-\Delta)^s u\,dx,\quad\forall u,v\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)?$$
I have no idea.

Comment: In your last equation, either you pick your functions in $H^{2s}(\mathbf{R}^n)$, or you replace $s$ by $s/2$ in the integrals. For your question you can check the *Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces* of Di Nezza, Palatucci and Valdinoci. I think Section 3 exactly does what you need. The preprint version of the document is available here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf

Comment: The case of $H^{2s}$ is valid for $s\in(0,1/2)$, but is $s\in[1/2,1)$??? Moreover in this article [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0867.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0867.pdf) at page 10 the authors state that: $$\mathcal{F}(-\Delta)^s v=|\cdot|^{2s}\mathcal{F}v,\quad\forall v\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n).$$ Studying "Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces" i can conclude by section 3 that: $$\mathcal{F}(-\Delta)^{s/2}=|\cdot|^s\mathcal{F}u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n),\quad\forall u\in H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n).$$ Which is different from what i have found in the article that i have linked.

Comment: I did not dig any further, but I would bet on a misprint in the paper you mentionned ... You should open a text book on functionnal analysis and search for a definition there.

Comment: Can you give me a reference please?

Comment: Did you check this post ? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299387/reference-on-spectral-fractional-laplacian